# Oracle Fetching the Result from two Different conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i

> I need to get the Values from tables with different conditions for a particular field. For Particular domain id (domain_id) there must be number of usernames assigned different system_id.

For specific system id (123) a column domain (domain_id ) should have the active  username only starts with 'a-' 0r 'A-' and all other username should be disabled except the username starts with 'a-' 0r 'A-'.

Please help to get the Expected result ;

**The Query I used as below:**

```
SELECT e.domain_id, e.first_name,  e.last_name, e.type, e.username,e.system_name
FROM (SELECT p.domain_id, p.first_name,p.last_name,p.type,  u.username, u.status, u.system_id ,s.system_name
            FROM ur_username u  JOIN ur_username_person up ON u.username_id = up.username_id JOIN ur_person p ON up.person_id = p.person_id
            JOIN ur_system s ON u.system_id = s.system_id
            WHERE    u.username LIKE 'A-%' OR   username LIKE 'a-%'
             AND u.status = 'ACTIVE'
            AND u.system_id = 349  ) E
    WHERE e.domain_id IN  ( SELECT p.domain_id
                FROM ur_username u
                JOIN ur_username_person up ON u.username_id = up.username_id
                JOIN ur_person p ON up.person_id = p.person_id
                WHERE u.status = 'DISABLED'
                AND  u.system_id = 349  )
```

Comment: Check the first letter: `select ascii(substr(username, 1, 1)) from ur_username` should return only `65` and `97`. It looks like you have usernames which begins from `A`/`a` from different alphabets (Cyrillic, for example).

Comment: @ Dmitry Thanks for the suggestion . But my main Concern is here is status . I am getting the result which is not matching with the Expected Result

Comment: OK. I thought that users were erroneously disabled and problem is here.

Comment: It looks like you need to put this condition in parenthesis: `WHERE    (u.username LIKE 'A-%' OR   username LIKE 'a-%') and ...`